# How can I change the log level for requests in Fastify?

Tags: fastify

```
const server = fastify({
    logger: {
        level: process.env.LOGLEVEL || 'debug',
        prettyPrint:
            process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'local'
                ? {
                      translateTime: 'HH:MM:ss',
                      ignore: 'pid,hostname',
                  }
                : false,
    },
});
```

`LOGLEVEL` is set to `trace`. But my requests are being logged at `info` level, which is higher than I want it to be:

```
[19:55:00] INFO: request completed
    res: {
      "statusCode": 200
    }
    responseTime: 8.38587498664856
    reqId: "req-1"
```

I don't think metrics like that belong at `info` level. How can I alter the logging setup so that request logging is at the `trace` level? I don't see any setting for this in the [docs about logging](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Logging/#usage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an official server option, [disableRequestLogging](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#disablerequestlogging), to fully disable it.

Then it is up to you to log with customized level in `onRequest` and `onRequests` hooks.